# ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch, early binding and VB6

Tags: .net, com, vb6, com-interop

I'm trying to understand how `ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch` is working and probably I misunderstand something. I have a VB6 application, some modern elements I'm implementing in .NET and I export it to COM. I declare interfaces and apply `InterfaceType`, but I have doubts if I do it in the right way. Problematic for me is `ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch`. Documentation for [ComInterfaceType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.cominterfacetype?view=netframework-4.6.2) says:

> InterfaceIsIDispatch - 2 - Indicates that an interface is exposed to COM
> as a dispinterface, which enables late binding only.

I made an example and when I add reference (tlb) in VB6 project, then I can use also class which implements `InterfaceIsIDispatch` as early binding.

After some tests I added also event, and it works for both classes.

What I'm missing?

```
// .NET

[Guid("138A3402-98AF-403D-B24D-0AB08FD79082")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IControllerIDispatch
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void ShowMessage();
}

[Guid("0F0D68FA-C7C4-4112-A2FB-DC3BFED77058")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IControllerDual
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void ShowMessage();
}

[Guid("745B2476-E82C-4ACF-BC79-D0BFA77D9F2E")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface PingEvents
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void Ping();
}

[Guid("653D8882-CFE5-4316-8B2A-395865CCBA05")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(PingEvents))]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class ControllerIDispatch : IControllerIDispatch
{
    public event Action Ping;

    public void ShowMessage()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(nameof(ControllerIDispatch));
        Volatile.Read(ref Ping)?.Invoke();
    }
}

[Guid("57C081B6-2607-4543-834A-77C1C9ECAAE8")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(PingEvents))]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class ControllerDual : IControllerDual
{
    public event Action Ping;

    public void ShowMessage()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(nameof(ControllerDual));
        Volatile.Read(ref Ping)?.Invoke();
    }
}


// VB6 example which works - both classes created using early binding

Dim WithEvents controllerDispatch As ControllerIDispatch
Dim WithEvents controllerDual As controllerDual

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set controllerDispatch = New ControllerIDispatch
    Set controllerDual = New ControllerDual
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Call controllerDispatch.ShowMessage
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Call controllerDual.ShowMessage
End Sub

Private Sub controllerDispatch_Ping()
    MsgBox "Dispatch Pong"
End Sub

Private Sub controllerDual_Ping()
    MsgBox "Dual Pong"
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not because you have intellisense on ShowMessage that you use early binding. It just mean there is a tlb.

Comment: You're being mislead by the VB6 editor, it knows how to use the type library you provided.  At runtime it behaves as if you'd have written Dim controllerDispatch As New Object.  So Command1_Click() does not use early binding.  One way to see that is to call it a million times (don't use MessageBox) and measure how long it takes.  Late binding is a lot slower.

Comment: @HansPassant interesting. I've done today another test, so I added `ComSourceInterfaces` to add events, and I'm able to declare in VB6 `Dim WithEvents controllerDispatch As ControllerIDispatch` and write handler to it - it shouldn't failed?

Comment: @HansPassant I made an update in the code. I extend example by com event and it still works, so I have doubts if VB6 changed early binding to late binding. From other side I checked `.tlb` by `oleview.exe` and classes which implements interfaces are marked as `coclass`, so it looks like I'm creating here concrete classes. How it is connected with attributes on interfaces? - I don't know yet.

Comment: Events in VB6 are always late-bound i.e. use dispinterfaces. You need dual interfaces for vtbl based calls (so called early-binding). Intellisense in VB6 IDE works with both dispinterfaces (only late-bound calls) and dual interfaces (both early and late-bound calls possible) so it proves nothing.

Comment: @wqw thank you for comment. I still can't see difference when one class inherits `ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch` and second `ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual`. Documentation points differences, but in my example I can't perceive it.

Comment: Dual interfaces are an optimization of dispinterfaces. Classic VB used to support only dispinterfaces until early-bound calls were introduced. COM servers usually implement dispinterfaces with a giant switch while vtable interface calls are akin to virtual function call (2 CPU instructions cheap). You were already proposed to excercise an empty method, calling in a loop to measure the performance gains.